# Vue-Cookies .set function isn't setting a cookie

Tags: javascript, rest, vue.js, cookies

Vue-Cookies .set function doesn't seem to set the cookie in Chrome, Safari or Firefox. Below is the code I'm using, called whenever someone authenticates:

```
vm.$cookies.set('token', response.headers.authorization)
```

Where "response.headers.authorization" is a real variable fetched from response data.

I get no errors in the console and I am able to see the site's cookies using the .keys function.

Does anyone have any ideas? I've posted a bigger block below to give some context.

```
 export default {
  name: 'Home',
  components: {},
  methods: {
    sso: function () {
      var vm = this;
      axios({
        method: 'POST',
        url: api + 'secure/use',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        data: {
          username: vm.$refs.username.value,
          password: vm.$refs.password.value
        }
      }).then(function (response) {
        vm.response = response.data;
        if (response.headers.authorization) {
          console.log(vm.$cookies.keys()) //THIS WORKS.
          vm.$cookies.set('token', response.headers.authorization) //THIS HAS NO EFFECT.
          vm.$router.push('/')
        } else {
          vm.error = true;
        }
      })
    }
  }...
```

Comment: Maybe you have to also set the expire time? E.g. vm.$cookies.set('token', response.headers.authorization, { expires: '1h' });

Comment: For vue-cookies it doesn't require you to specify an expiry date. I've just actually managed to fix it by renaming the title of the cookie from 'token' to 'TOKEN'. Very weird fix and I'm unsure why that was an issue.